# Little Endian vs Big Endian?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture

Suppose a processor uses the big endian representation and x is a 32-bit integer stored in memory starting at the memory address 1000. The memory is byte-addressable, each location holding a byte. Specify in binary what would be in memory location 1000, 1001, 1002 and 1003 if the program has the statement:

int x = 1023;

---

I know that the big-endian representation has the MSB at the lowest memory location, but how to use that in this question?

Comment: You are wrong...big endian is analogous to how we write numbers. The MSB is leftmost byte and LSB is the rightmost byte with byte order increasing from right to left. Moving to your question you need to convert 1023 to binary representation and then figure out how to write it in big endian ordering.

Comment: It is correct that the MSB is stored in the memory location with the smallest address though.